# .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, no-www

How do I make it so all traffic is directed for the entire site and all subdirectories from non-`www` to `www`.

Here is my .htaccess contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/vivalast
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please ensure you read rules before continuing to post unnecessary duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```